# Discord.js-commando how would I check if a mentioned user has a role, like a muted role for example?

Tags: discord.js

So I have been trying to figure out how to check if the mentioned user has the muted role before attempting to add it, and if they do, say they are already muted, and I can't figure it out. Here is my code for my mute command, any help is appreciated.

```
const { Command } = require('discord.js-commando');
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = class MuteCommand extends Command {
  constructor(client) {
    super(client, {
      name: 'mute',
      aliases: ['mute-user'],
      memberName: 'mute',
      group: 'guild',
      description:
        'Mutes a tagged user (if you have already created a Muted role)',
      guildOnly: true,
      userPermissions: ['MANAGE_ROLES'],
      clientPermissions: ['MANAGE_ROLES'],
      args: [
        {
          key: 'userToMute',
          prompt: 'Please mention the member that you want to mute them.',
          type: 'member'
        },
        {
          key: 'reason',
          prompt: 'Why do you want to mute this user?',
          type: 'string',
          default: message =>
            `${message.author.tag} Requested, no reason was given`
        }
      ]
    });
  }

  run(message, { userToMute, reason }) {
    const mutedRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(
      role => role.name === 'Muted'
    );
    if (!mutedRole)
      return message.channel.send(
        ':x: No "Muted" role found, create one and try again.'
      );
    const user = userToMute;
    if (!user)
      return message.channel.send(':x: Please try again with a valid user.');
    user.roles
      .add(mutedRole)
      .then(() => {
        const muteEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
          .addField('Muted:', user)
          .addField('Reason', reason)
          .setColor('#420626');
        message.channel.send(muteEmbed);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        message.reply(
          ':x: Something went wrong when trying to mute this user.'
        );
        return console.error(err);
      });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see if a mentioned user has a role you can do:

```
member = message.mentions.first();
if (member._roles.includes('<role ID>') {
  //code
}
```

and obviously, replace `<role ID>` with the role id of the muted role.

This works because `members` objects have a `_roles` array that contains all the IDs of the roles they have.

Comment: If I replace <role id> with mutedRole.id would it still work and get the id of a role named Muted? mutedRole is defined in my code